# Xamarin Android Player with OpenGL ES 3.x

Tags: opengl-es, xamarin-android-player

I want to install an app that requires OpenGL ES 3.0, however it looks like all of the device/android version pairings only use 2.0, even though from what I understand many of them should support it.

Did I miss a particular combination, is there some other way to get it to use 3, or is this a restriction of the player/Virtualbox (and if so, where would be the correct place to request this)?